# How to efficiently do this mysql query? (Join and Check existence)

Tags: php, mysql

I'm doing a mysql query where I want to join two tables (Projects and Country):

```
+----------------+  +-------------------------+
| Project ID     |  | id                      |
+----------------+  +-------------------------+
| Name           |  | name                    |
+----------------+  +-------------------------+
| countryid      |  | lat, long (two columns) |
+----------------+  +-------------------------+
```

I'm using this query:

```
SELECT country.name, country.latitude, country.longitude
                    FROM projects JOIN country ON projects.countryid = country.id;
```

Fine until now! What happens next is each project has a class (TO-DO, DOING, DONE). Each class is one table that has all the project ids that belong to each.

> The structure has to be like this, because each class has additional information. And that information only exists if the project belongs to that class. For example, a project in the TO-DO class has a "start_prevision_date" which is only valid in the TO-DO table (fields from other classes are still null).

What I want to do is assign one color to each project depending if he is TO-DO, DOING or DONE. A perfect solution would be a query that return values like:

```
ResultSet:
+--------------+------------------+-------------------+-------+-------+------+
| country.name | country.latitude | country.longitude | TO-DO | DOING | DONE |
+--------------+------------------+-------------------+-------+-------+------+
| Portugal     | 13,4             | 15,6              |   1   |   0   |   0  |
+--------------+------------------+-------------------+-------+-------+------+
```

*Can be in more than one column at once*

Where 1 means he belongs and 0 means he doesn't belong. I could just check, and print the right color!

Is there a way to do this efficiently? Avoiding the use of extra three queries.

I hope I was clear.

Comment: Why three extra queries? You have all information to decide that in PHP (probably a sequence of three ifs). Alternatively, put TODO, DOING, DONE in a single field (possibly of type ENUM), as they seem to be mutually excluding.

Comment: I only have that information if I have the right query...
Otherwise I would be doing a mysql query per check.

Comment: Please post your complete tables structure

Comment: And it is generally a bad habit to use an operator (the minus) in an identifier (although it may be possible in SQL by including the identifier in backticks; did not try it). Consider removing it or use an underscore instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a query like this:

```
SELECT 
country.name,
country.latitude,
country.longitude,
   IF (TO-DO.sureField IS NULL, 0, 1) as TO-DO,
   IF (DOING.sureField IS NULL, 0, 1) as DOING,
   IF (DONE.sureField IS NULL, 0, 1) as DONE
FROM projects
LEFT JOIN country ON projects.countryid = country.id
LEFT JOIN TO-DO ON projects.projectid = TO-DO.projectid
LEFT JOIN DOING ON projects.projectid = DOING.projectid
LEFT JOIN DONE ON projects.projectid = DONE.projectid;
```

sureField has to be a field in each class table that is surely populated and not null when a project is in that class and null otherwise.

I tested in MySql reproducing a similar case and it worked.

This will give you:

```
ResultSet:
+--------------+------------------+-------------------+-------+-------+------+  
| country.name | country.latitude | country.longitude | TO-DO | DOING | DONE |  
+--------------+------------------+-------------------+-------+-------+------+  
| Portugal     | 13,4             | 15,6              |   1   |   1   |   0  |  
+--------------+------------------+-------------------+-------+-------+------+
```

If the projects in DOING remain also in TO-DO, or:

```
ResultSet:
+--------------+------------------+-------------------+-------+-------+------+
| country.name | country.latitude | country.longitude | TO-DO | DOING | DONE |
+--------------+------------------+-------------------+-------+-------+------+
| Portugal     | 13,4             | 15,6              |   0   |   1   |   0  |
+--------------+------------------+-------------------+-------+-------+------+
```

If the projects in DOING are deleted from TO-DO.

Therefore you will have to manage the query on result set appropriately.

Regards

Comment: Thank you for your time. It seems like the solution, I will test it.